# Showing custom loader on Nuxt (vue.js) on ajax call

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

In the nuxt config file,
While setting loading to true, then I saw the loader bar while call ajax.

But if I change to custom loader (https://nuxtjs.org/examples/custom-loading/)

And set the loading config file to my custom component

```
loading: '~/components/loading.vue',
```

then the componenet apear just when route change but not on ajax calls